# How can I throw exception inside the try block and terminate the program

Tags: java, exception

My program takes input from the console as `DD/MM/YYYY` representing a date.
I store all the data accordingly.
 In this try catch block i am checking if variable "m" is a correct month, regarding the day and being between 1 and 12.

If "m" is not a number, the `NumberFormatException` is thrown. 
I want to be able to throw the exceptions inside the if conditions and terminate the program displaying the thrown error and the message associated to it.

```
try
{
m = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
if (m < 1 && m > 12)
    throw new NumberFormatException(m + " luna invalida");
else if ((m > 8 && m % 2 != 0 && d == 31) || (m < 8 && m % 2 == 0 && d == 31))
    throw new NumberFormatException(m + " " + d + " luna,zi invalida");
else
    luna = month[m];

} catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    m = 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the try-catch and add a throws declaration to your method

Comment: You can re-throw an exception: `throw new RuntimeException(e)` it is better to declare your method throws as the above comment, but sometimes this is appropriate too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the `Integer.parseInt(data[1])` inside a try-catch block but all of the other code outside it. If you're using `parseInt` often, you could have the conversion inside a function.

```
m = 0;
try {
    m = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Rest of the code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the catch block. Type this

```
      System.exit(0).
```

Im using it in javafx gui.